# How to obtain the symbolic expression for the integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I need to evaluate the following expression,

$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \frac{d}{d x} \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{-\alpha}(\exp(\lambda t)) d t, 0<\alpha<1, \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$

using *Mathematica* to obtain $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k} x^{k-\alpha}}{\Gamma(k+1-\alpha)}$.

So I used the following code

```
Assuming[
 Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && Re[- α] > -1, 
 1/Gamma[1 - α] D[Integrate[(x - t)^(-α) Exp[λ t], {t, 0, x}], x]
]
```

And obtain the following output

```
(λ^α (x λ)^-α + E^(x λ) λ^α (Gamma[1 - α] - Gamma[1 - α, x λ]))/Gamma[1 - α]
```

Can anyone please help me to obtain the equation

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k} x^{k-\alpha}}{\Gamma(k+1-\alpha)}$

Comment: A definite integral of a function $f(t)$ with respect to $t$ in the limits $0\le t\le x$ cannot depend on $t$

Comment: if you do this to your result `Map[FullSimplify, 
 Series[%1, {x, 0, 5}, Assumptions -> x > 0] // Normal // Expand]` you can check that  it works

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you can take the n-th term of the expansion of the exponent (which is as you know, `(l*t)^n/n!` where I put `l` instead of lambda. Then integrate it:

```
Assuming[
 n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers && Re[x] > 0 && Im[x] == 0 && 
  Re[-\[Alpha]] > -1, 
 1/Gamma[1 - \[Alpha]] D[
   Integrate[(x - t)^(-\[Alpha])*(l*t)^n/n!, {t, 0, x}], x]]

(*  (l^n x^(n - \[Alpha]) (1 + n - \[Alpha]))/Gamma[
 2 + n - \[Alpha]]   *)
```

and here you get it.

Have fun!